# Bluebird - Promise.resolve doesn't work but return works

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

I have this function which returns a Promise

```
save(data) => {
    return mymongo.insert(data).then(
        (result) => { 
           console.log('hello mongo');
           console.log(result);
           return Promise.resolve(result); 
        }
    )
}
```

in my router I call that function

```
app.post('/printers', (req, res, next) => {
    save(req.body).then(
        (result) => {
            console.log('hello') // is not called, nothing is printed
            console.log(result) // is not called
            res.send(result)
        }
    ).catch(res.send);
});
```

then with curl I do the request

```
curl -v -d '{ ... }' -X POST http://localhost:8080/printers
```

It is pretty fast and looks fine

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /printers HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 35
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 35 out of 35 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2
< ETag: W/"2-vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
< Date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 01:01:30 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

so no timeout but no response and in console I see only the logs from save()

```
hello mongo
{ .... }
```

when I replace `return Promise.resolve(result)` with `return result` then I receive the response from the server and `console.log(result)` gets executed and in my console I see

```
hello mongo
{ .... }
hello
{ .... }
```

Comment: well `return Promise.resolve(result);` is usually redundant, though if `result` were some other (non bluebird in your case) *thenable* it would make a difference - but `result` in your case is **not** a `thenable` - can you try `console.log(Promise.resolve.toString())` where you use it, and see if it outputs something like `function (obj) {
    var ret = tryConvertToPromise(obj);
    if (!(ret instanceof Promise)) {
        ret = new Promise(INTERNAL);
        ret._captureStackTrace();
        ret._setFulfilled();
        ret._rejectionHandler0 = obj;
    }
    return ret;
}`

Comment: also, try to put some logging in your `.catch` - perhaps there's an error that will be useful to you

Comment: `return Promise.resolve(result); ` is not needed. Just do `return result;` and as long as i think, there is an issue with your mongo implementation and not the code apart from what i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem with the mongodb implementation of promises, since the return value in the `insert(...).then` callback is treated by that implementation. I don't find any reference that it is Promise/A+ compliant, and your code seems to prove it is not.

If your concern is to use the Promise API of your liking (probably bluebird in your case), then do the conversion at an earlier stage, so you are not dependent on mongodb's `then` implementation:

```
save(data) => {
    return Promise.resolve(mymongo.insert(data)).then(
        (result) => { 
           console.log('hello mongo');
           console.log(result);
           return result;
        }
    )
}
```